# Is it possible to force a mapping, server side, on a specific index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I send to Elasticsearch data to a index `mydata`. This index may or may not exist when the data reaches Elasticsearch and is automatically created.

The mapping guessed from my data was correct up to now, when I added a new field of [`geo_point`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/geo-point.html) type. This type, as far as I understand, must be explicitly provided with a mapping.

My understanding is that mapping is handled

- either dynamicall, like my case
- or when [creating an index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-mapping-introduction#how-to-provide-a-mapping) "manually"
- or via the [Put Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html)

None of these solutions work for me, the index is deleted / recreated rarely (but unpredictibly) and adding the mapping to each document sent to the server would be too much.

**Is there a way to store, on the server, an information of the type *"if you create  index `mydata`, the field `position` must be of type `geo_ip`"*?**

Comment: [Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) will do exactly what you need. You should investigate that a little bit.

Comment: @Val: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for and missed it somehow. Would you be so kind and just copy your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Also - since the doc does not mention that - can the mapping be partial, in other words just mention one filed and its mapping, leaving the rest to be auto-discovered? (I guess "yes" because it is close to the problems with "Multiple Templates Matching" and is also the most logical way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) will do exactly what you need. Simply create a template (with mappings and settings) whose name matches your index name and as soon as a new document comes in for an index that doesn't exist yet, the latter will be automatically create with the proper mappings and settings.

To answer your second question, yes, your mapping may only contain the definition of a few fields (the `geo_point` you mentioned, etc) and you can let ES map the other ones dynamically.

Comment: @yes it did, thank you (and also for the gentle reminder to accept after my +1). You are a saver when it comes to ES :)